After JDK 17 migration JSP content not visible
Getting below warning
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-4) No mapping for POST /VisitVerification/allmodal.ac
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-5) No mapping for POST /VisitVerification/main.action
Used below dependency
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

taglib used like below, is anything needs to be chnaged to jakarta ?
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%
String ProfileName = (String)session.getAttribute("ProfileName"); 
%>


In case you - or someone else - still needs an answer:
You also need to replace the taglib URI in your JSPs from http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/### to jakarta.tags.###
